# Bayseian Inference: Asymptotic Normal Approximation

Tags: statistics, bayesian

**The Question:**

Given random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n \overset{i.i.d.}{\sim}\text{Ber}(\theta)$, where $\theta \in (0,1)$ has a $\text{Beta}(a,b)$ prior distribution $$\pi(\theta)=\frac{1}{B(a,b)}\theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}.$$

(i) Obtain the normal approximation distribution to the posterior distribution.

(ii) Verify that the mean and variance of the approximation are approximately $\dfrac rn$ and $\dfrac{r(n-r)}{n^3}$ respectively, where $r=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$.

---

**My Attempt:**

So I started by computing the MLE of $\theta$, which we know is $$\hat \theta = \frac rn$$

The density function for Bernoulli is $$f(x_i)=\theta^{x_i}(1-\theta)^{1-x_i}$$

The likelihood function is then $$L(\theta)=\theta^r(1-\theta)^{n-r}$$

The log likelihood is $$l(\theta)=\ln[L(\theta)]=r\ln(\theta)+(n-r)\ln(1-\theta)$$

The observed information is
\begin{align}
\ & J(\theta)=-\frac{d^2l}{d\theta^2}=\frac{r}{\theta^2}+\frac{n-r}{(1-\theta)^2} \\
\ \implies & J(\hat \theta) = \frac{r}{(r/n)^2}+\frac{n-r}{(1-r/n)^2}=\frac{n^3}{r(n-r)}
\end{align}

Hence the normal approximation is $$\theta\mid\vec x \approx \text N(\hat \theta,J(\hat \theta)^{-1})=\text N \biggl(\frac rn, \frac{r(n-r)}{n^3} \biggr)$$

I have not used the beta prior at all, and from what question (ii) is asking, I have clearly misunderstood something...

Comment: I think you got it right, aside from forgetting to incorporate the multiple observations into your likelihood. The second derivatives of the Fisher information evaluated at the MLE gives you the covariance of the asymptotic normal approximation; centered at the MLE. 

The book could have meant like a Laplace approximation to the posterior in finite samples, but that would be kind of an unusual interpretation of that.

Comment: The previous statement is true given some restrictions on the parameter space. If you're reading about the [Bernstein von Mises](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bernstein-von_Mises_theorem) theorem that approach would be an application of that

Answer (score 1):

1. Since given one observation $X = x$, the posterior distribution of $θ$ is ${\mit Β}(a + x, b + 1 - x)$, then given $n$ obersavtions $x_1, \cdots, x_n$, the posterior distribution of $θ$ is$$
   {\mit Β}\left(a + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n x_k, b + n - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n x_k\right) = {\mit Β}(a + r, b + n - r).
   $$
   Because the mean and the variance of ${\mit Β}(a + r, b + n - r)$ are $\dfrac{a + r}{a + b + n}$ and $\dfrac{(a + r)(b + n - r)}{(a + b + n)^2(a + b + n + 1)}$, respectively, then the normal approximation of posterior distribution is$$
   N\left( \frac{a + r}{a + b + n}, \frac{(a + r)(b + n - r)}{(a + b + n)^2(a + b + n + 1)} \right).
   $$

   For large $n$, because $r ≈ n θ_0$, where $θ_0$ is the true value of $θ$, then$$
   \frac{a + r}{a + b + n} = \frac{\dfrac{a}{n} + \dfrac{r}{n}}{\dfrac{a + b}{n} + 1} ≈ \dfrac{r}{n},
   $$\begin{align*}
   \frac{(a + r)(b + n - r)}{(a + b + n)^2(a + b + n + 1)} &= \frac{\left(\dfrac{a}{n} + \dfrac{r}{n}\right)\left(\dfrac{b}{n} + 1 - \dfrac{r}{n}\right)}{n\left(\dfrac{a + b}{n} + 1\right)^2\left(\dfrac{a + b}{n} + 1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)}\\
   &≈ \frac{\dfrac{r}{n} \left( 1 - \dfrac{r}{n} \right)}{n} = \frac{r(n - r)}{n^3}.
   \end{align*}

Comment: In the first question where you went from the Beta posterior to the Normal approximation, is it some sort of corollary of the CLT or is that just the way it is?

Comment: @glowstonetrees I don't know how exactly approximation of distribution is defined on your book, so I just make the first and the second moment of the two distributions equal.